# Excel Find And Replace Text in Formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have 3 columns: A and B contain numbers, and C has a html link.
I want to replace numbers in the html link with the numbers from columns A & B.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? I tried using the replace function, but it doesnt work for multiple variables.

Example:
random.com/do?ID=1111&SourceID=2222 
I'd replace 1111 with ID columan A 617 and 2222 with sourceID column B 2

```
SourceID LocationID link
617     2           random.com/do?ID=1111&SourceID=2222 
1878     39         random.com/do?ID=1111&SourceID=2222  
4148     48         random.com/do?ID=1111&SourceID=2222
```

Comment: can you give an example?  What numbers do you want to replace?

Comment: Can you update your question with the new information so it is more readable.  It is hard to tell in the comments what data is in Column A and Column B.  You can throw that information in a `code block` so it is formatted correctly

Comment: Don't try to post the information as comments as it is unreadable here, click on the **edit** button under your question, then paste your information there.  You can format then things _inside your question_ (not in the comments), by highlighting text and clicking on the **`{}`** symbol to format the highlighted text as code

Comment: ah okay i got it now!
thank you for your patience. I've updated my question

Comment: Thanks, that is a lot more readable, I am assuming that `SourceID` is really column B as you said in your description but just note it is backwards in your example as it looks like it is in column A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **not** use the replace formula here because it requires a "position and length" which will change once you update the link with a new value from SourceID or LocationID and the logic to figure out the new location is overkill and not needed.

Instead you can use the **`Substitute`** formula instead which I think is more readable and easier to implement.  This formula replaces "text" with "text"

If you use 2 `Substitutes` (1 outer and 1 nested) you can replace both strings in one line.  Try putting this in column D

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"1111",A1),"2222",B1)
```

and you can auto-fill down